# Why inputting 'nul' in windows cmd gives a certain error-message

Tags: windows, filesystems, internet-security

Whenever I type 'nul' into the command prompt (whichever directory Im currently in) I get a "Windows Security"-popup saying this:

```
    Windows Security

    Your Internet Security settings prevented one or more files 
    from being opened.

    $uri$\nul
```

I know why opening nul would be an.. interesting concept (fyi: it´s impossible). But why is the box saying "Your **internet security settings**[..]"? The 'nul'-file has **nothing** to do with my internet security settings, as far as I know, at least.

**EDIT:** Also, why is the command prompt recognizing 'nul' as some sort of command? Shouldnt it error with (as it does with most other reserved keywords):

```
    ´X´ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
    or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nul` is being recognized as a command because it *exists* as far as standard file I/O functions are concerned, just like `/dev/null` exists. (Opening `nul` *is* possible, but the end result would likely be as if you opened a zero-length file.)

As for the notification – Windows uses different security levels called "zones" (local computer, Internet, intranet, trusted, restricted). When you download a file, most browsers mark it as coming from the "Internet" zone, so a confirmation is displayed even though the file is now on your disk. It's possible that `nul` for some reason belongs to the "Restricted" zone now. (Zones were initially limited to website contents in Internet Explorer, only later expanded to cover downloaded files and other things.)

Comment: So the security-zones actually exist outside of Internet Explorer? That could explain _alot!_ Thanks for your answer!